# How to iterate over nodes to run commands in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to iterate over a list computers and run a command while on the respective node. Problem is whenever I run it I get a NullPointerException.

In the console log it shows that it is running on the first node in the array but does not get farther than that.

I have tried putting the nodes in a stage but no luck with that either.

```
println computerList //Array of node names to be iterated

@NonCPS
def echo_all(list) {
    list.each { 
    node("${it}"){
        echo "Hello World"
    }
  }
}

echo_all(computerList)
```

I expect the results to run Hello World on each of the respective machines in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of running a shell command on all nodes that have a particular label. 
I'm doing "uname -a" rather than echo "Hello World" so the node name will be displayed.

```
label = "database_servers"
echo "Will run on hosts with label ${label}"

listOfNodeNames = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect {
  node -> node.getLabelString().contains(label) ? node.name : null
}
listOfNodeNames.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null))

for (node_to_run_on in listOfNodeNames) {
    println "Node: " + node_to_run_on
    node ("${node_to_run_on}") {
        stage("Run uname on ${node_to_run_on}") {
            sh ("uname -a")
        }
    }
}
```